# Commands not executing from ArcToolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox

I can easily open and type all the appropriate things in the various tools, but when I execute the tools, it just shows an hourglass in the results window and nothing never happens. This is the same for all tools.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall Is likely to address this.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to answer with little information, but you should try to disable the background processing: go to geoprocessing / geoprocessing option, then uncheck the box for the background processing.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that this isn't a *solution*, just a way to verify that the install is corrupt.